# Split one column into multiple rows in R

Tags: r

I have data in this format (2 columns) :

**data .......... index**
city1 ............1
person1.......2
telephone1...3
city2..............1
city3..............1
telephone3....3

I've added the second column to know which kind of data each row represents (1-city, 2-person, 3-telephone).

What I need is this (1,2,3 to become the column names) :

**1................2..................3**
city1.......person1...telephone1
city2........NULL..........NULL
city3........NULL........telephone3

How can I do this in R ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution

```
#sample data
dd<-data.frame(
    data= c("city1","person1","telephone1","city2","city3","telephone3"),
    index=c(1,2,3,1,1,3),
    stringsAsFactors=F
)

#assign new row when index stays the same or decreases
row<-cumsum(c(1,diff(dd$index))<1)+1

#create empty matrix to hold result
mm<-matrix(character(), nrow=max(row), ncol=max(dd$index))

#put values where they belong
mm[cbind(row, dd$index)]<-dd$data
```

And that returns

```
#      [,1]    [,2]      [,3]        
# [1,] "city1" "person1" "telephone1"
# [2,] "city2" NA        NA          
# [3,] "city3" NA        "telephone3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the numbers embedded in the `data` column as the row index, with MrFlick's data:

```
dd<-data.frame(
    data= c("city1","person1","telephone1","city2","city3","telephone3"),
    index=c(1,2,3,1,1,3),
    stringsAsFactors=F
)

r <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D*", "", dd$data))
m <- matrix(,nrow=max(r), ncol=max(dd$index))
m[cbind(r, dd$index)] <- dd$data
m

     [,1]    [,2]      [,3]        
[1,] "city1" "person1" "telephone1"
[2,] "city2" NA        NA          
[3,] "city3" NA        "telephone3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility: create a "time" variable and use `reshape` or `dcast` from "reshape2".

Using @MrFlick's sample data, here's the "time" variable. However, this assumes that your data are already in the correct order:

```
dd$time <- cumsum(dd$index == 1) ## Similar to MrFlick's approach...
```

Here's the `reshape` approach:

```
reshape(dd, direction = "wide", idvar="time", timevar="index")
#   time data.1  data.2     data.3
# 1    1  city1 person1 telephone1
# 4    2  city2    <NA>       <NA>
# 5    3  city3    <NA> telephone3
```

And here's the `dcast` approach:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dd, time ~ index, value.var="data")
#   time     1       2          3
# 1    1 city1 person1 telephone1
# 2    2 city2    <NA>       <NA>
# 3    3 city3    <NA> telephone3
```

---

(Just FYI, MrFlick's answer will most likely be the fastest because of the use of matrix indexing. `reshape` is reasonably efficient with smaller datasets, but slows down quickly. If speed is an issue with `dcast`, check out `dcast.data.table` instead.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I first tried with reshape, I was just missing the time variable.